# Does 'extraordinary', 'exceptional', 'outstanding' always carry positive connotations nowadays?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms, history, ambiguity

When I take the word 'extraordinary', 'exceptional' and 'outstanding' literally, it simply means something 'out of the ordinary', 'rare and/or unusual', or something which 'stands out from the rest', but not necessarily conferring any positive connotations. And indeed this is reflected in the dictionary.

**[Extraordinary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extraordinary)**

> 1. **beyond what is usual, ordinary, regular, or established**
> 2. exceptional in character, amount, extent, degree, etc.; noteworthy; remarkable

**[Exceptional](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exceptional)**

> 1. **forming an exception or rare instance; unusual; extraordinary**
> 2. unusually excellent; superior

**[Outstanding](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outstanding)**

> 1. **prominent; conspicuous; striking**
> 2. marked by superiority or distinction; excellent; distinguished

However, very rarely do I see text use these three words, by themselves, without conferring a positive connotation (see the second definitions). If they choose to convey something as out of the ordinary without carrying a positive connotation, they'd use words such as 'striking', 'unusual', 'uncommon' or 'strange'.

You can of course attach negative connotations using, for example, 'exceptionally bad' to attach 'exceptionally' to the first definition. But if I say, this taste is 'extraordinary', you'd immediately associate it with being positive, while it might just be plain [weird](http://www.bustle.com/articles/20221-11-disgusting-jelly-bean-flavors-you-wont-believe-exist).

**So are the 'literal' definitions of these words, in and of itself, now obsolete?**

Comment: How extraordinary that you think so. I personally find nothing exceptional about using the more literal senses of at least the first two. Outstanding payments aside, however, I’d agree that the literal meaning of _outstanding_ is at least archaic.

Comment: I think this is Off Topic (Primarily Opinion-based). Or a peeve, given thousands of written instances of [*an outstanding **failure***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+outstanding+failure%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have never read such a phrase use in normal usage, LSNED. If you go on the web search, most of the results are from books, and not very common books I may add.

Comment: @dayuloli: Obviously [*an outstanding **success***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+outstanding+success%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is far more common - so much so that dictionaries would invariably specifically refer to the "positive associations" usage. But the answer to your actual question can only be *"Not **always**"*, and everything else is just opinions.

Comment: ...and you don't really need [exceptional circumstances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22exceptional+circumstances%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) to find examples of your other words being used in neutral/negative contexts.

Comment: Certainly one can be exceptionally stupid, or suffer from an outstanding failure.  The words standing by themselves, however, (eg, "is exceptional") generally indicate superiority.  (They may, however, be used in stand-alone fashion in an ironic statement, but that would have to be interpreted from the larger context.)

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, but not necessarily. Here are some examples where they have negative connotations:

> A new, extraordinary tax was imposed by the government.
>
> Theirs was an exceptionally stupid idea.
>
> You have outstanding debts.

Granted, the last one is cheating since this is a different meaning of *outstanding*, but it is certainly not a good connotation.

As a general rule, those words carry good connotations because very often being different from the norm is considered as better than the norm. However, as usual, context is everything:

> He is an extraordinarily bad father.
>
> She is an exceptionally bad mother.
>
> They are outstandingly bad parents.

In other words, while these terms do indeed most often carry a good connotation, they can and will be understood to carry a bad one in the right context.

My gut feeling is that of the three, *outstanding* is the one least likely to be associated with a negative connotation (though it will be understood if used in such a context), while both *exceptional* and, even more so, *extraordinary* can more often be used in such a way.

Finally, some real world examples:

- From the Free Dictionary's [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egregious) of *egregious*:

  > 1. outstandingly bad; flagrant: an egregious lie.
- From [an article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2014/12/09/the-oecds-extraordinarily-bad-report-on-inequality-and-gdp-growth/) in Forbes magazine:

  > The OECD's Extraordinarily Bad Report On Inequality And GDP Growth
- From the Free Dictionary's [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/atrocious) of *atrocious*:

  > 2. Exceptionally bad; abominable: atrocious decor; atrocious behavior.

---

As pointed out by @JanusBahsJacquet below, my examples above are all about the adverb and not the adjective. True, that is cheating. Of the adjectives, *extraordinary* is the one most often used for neutral or bad connotations while *outstanding* (in the sense mentioned in the OP) and *exceptional* are indeed almost always positive in the absence of qualifiers.

*Extraordinary* on the other hand, is really quite often used negatively. In addition to *extraordinary tax*, you also have *extraordinary circumstances*, *extraordinary request*, *extraordinary needs*, none of which imply anything good.

Comment: Most of your examples are kind of cheating: just because the literal meaning of the _adjective_ starts to be eclipsed by the derived sense, it doesn’t necessarily follow that the corresponding _adverb_ has to follow suit. All these three adverbs are just emphasisers, really, and thus more or less impervious to positive/negative slanting—the adjective they modify handle that. As adjectives, though, they _have_ to have a positive/negative slant.

Comment: I totally agree with everything you said here. Context is everything as always. I think what I really meant to ask is if those words are used by themselves, are they always positive. In your examples, you used 'exceptionally stupid', 'extraordinary tax' etc. The 'stupid' and 'tax' themselves carry negative connotation, which sways the meaning of the preceding words.

Comment: @dayuloli well, _extraordinary_ is the most neutral of the three. It is often used to describe bad things. _Extraordinary circumstances_ for example, is more often bad than good.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet fair enough. I admit that _outstanding_ and _exceptional_ are almost always good in the absence of qualifiers. _Extraordinary_, however, is quite often used in a negative or neutral way. See updated answer.

Comment: The examples such as "extraordinarily bad, stupid, etc." still show a usage that implies "to a greater extent than normal," rather than "to a lesser extent."  A greater extent of "bad" or "stupid" is negative, but still within the meaning of "extraordinary" as "more so than usual," rather than "less so."  That having been said, what we now call "special needs children" have been called in medical literature "exceptional," implying less capability than most children have, but that's a fairly archaic usage.